# Foreach loop $key => $value

Tags: php, foreach

```
$suggestions = array();

    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->where('deleted',0);
    $this->db->like('name', $search);
    $this->db->limit($limit);
    $by_name = $this->db->get();

    $temp_suggestions = array();

    foreach($by_name->result() as $row)
    {
        if ($row->category && $row->size)
        {
            $temp_suggestions[$row->item_id] =  $row->name . ' ('.$row->category.', '.$row->size.')'.' Unit Price: '. $row->unit_price;
        }
        elseif ($row->category)
        {
            $temp_suggestions[$row->item_id] =  $row->name . ' ('.$row->category.')'.' Unit Price: '.$row->unit_price;
        }
        elseif ($row->size)
        {
            $temp_suggestions[$row->item_id] =  $row->name . ' ('.$row->size.')'.' Unit Price: '.$row->unit_price;
        }
        else
        {
            $temp_suggestions[$row->item_id] = $row->name.' Unit Price: '.$row->unit_price;         
        }

    }

    asort($temp_suggestions);

    foreach($temp_suggestions as $key => $value)
    {
        $suggestions[]=array('value'=> $key, 'label' => $value); // Please take a look at this line     
    }
```

hi please see commented line, that foreach loop only display 2 columns from 9 columns,  they are key and value. key contains ID and values display value of  Qty column
So the question is:

how to modify this foreach loop to  get ALL column of query with foreach loop?

Comment: Maybe do a `print_r($temp_suggestions)` before the loop and write down the output.

Comment: @gmk: No, in PHP `$a[] = item;` will always add a new item to the array.

Comment: hi gmk, i dont need last column

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$temp_suggestions` contains *rows*, not *columns*.  To get all the data from each row, you must insert that data into `$temp_suggestions` in the prior loop.  For example, to return all the columns as a comma-separated list indexed by the item_id:

```
foreach($by_name->result() as $row) {
    $temp_suggestions[$row->item_id] = implode(', ', (array) $row);
}
```

Comment: hi Peter Gluck, it works, but how to access on each row? thanks